# how to configuration gstreamer(android-tutorial-1) in eclipse?

Tags: android, android-ndk, gstreamer

I use Windows-7 and I want to run gstreamer android-tutorial-1 in eclipse!

I do these steps:

1. Run eclipse (download and run it : `https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-android-developers/neonm6`)
2. Set SDK path(`E:\androidSDK`) and NDK path(`E:\androidNDK\build`) to eclipse! I use `android-ndk-r13b-windows-x86_64`
3. Import `android-tutorial-1` from `E:\gstreamerSDK\share\gst-sdk\tutorials` and create `tutorial1.so` file by `add native support`!
4. Now, I define `GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT_ANDROID` to `window->preferences->C/C++->Build->Environment` by `E:/gstreamerSDK` value!
5. Clean project

Now, when I build project:

[Complete output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrNAe.png)

```
E:/androidNDK/build//../platforms/android-21/arch-arm64/usr/include\asm/sigcontext.h:44:2: error: unknown type name '__uint128_t'
 __uint128_t vregs[32];
 ^
gst-build/gstreamer_android.c:385:58: error: format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure) [-Werror,-Wformat-security]
    __android_log_print (ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "GStreamer", message);
                                                         ^~~~~~~
2 errors generated.
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You use `clang` as compiler, isn't it?

Comment: __uint128_t: This appears to be an outstanding bug in eclipse: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=444577

Comment: I don't know what is my compiler! I have SDK and NDK, than extract eclipse, than do above steps... @CAMOBAP

Comment: ok! what i do? use Android studio instead of eclipse? my eclipse is `neonm6` @DavidWohlferd

Comment: @amnpoya could you please attach `ndk-build` log instead eclipse log?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use older Android-NDK where sigcontext structure contains "long" instead of "__uint128_t" or even use "arch-arm" instead of "arch-arm64" if possible (GStreamer samples compile fine with i.e. NDK r9).